# Are there infinitely many $m$ such that $2^{2m+1}+17$ is a perfect square?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, square-numbers

My attempt: clearly when $m=1$, $2^{2m+1}+17=25$ is a perfect square. I conjecture that there are only finitely many $m$ such that $2^{2m+1}+17$ is a perfect square, and this might be obtained by considering modulo some value (e.g., 3, 8, etc), but I could not figure out the detail.

On the other hand, this question would be much easier if one looks at $2^{2m}+17$.

Please help.

Comment: In the range $[0,10^5]$ , the only $m$ , such that $2^{2m+1}+17$ is a perfect power , are $1,2$ and $4$. In those cases, it is even a perfect square.

Comment: Well, more broadly, [Pillai's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture) would tell us that there can only be finitely many perfect powers that differ by $17$, though of course that conjecture is still open (might be known for $17$ specifically, not sure about that).

Comment: @lulu The general case is known only for difference $1$ , but special cases might be completely solvable.

Comment: For the perfect squares, I even completed the search range upto $m=10^6$. No further solution.

Comment: @Sil Is this related to the Nagell-equation ?

Comment: @Peter It seems so, the linked post gives reference to an article which shows only odd $x=2m+1$ solutions are $x=3,5,9$, hence $m=1,2,4$. Though the answer feels like link only without much details itself.

Comment: Basically it follows from $y^2-2x^4=17$ and $y^2-8x^4=17$ being impossible for $x\equiv 0 \pmod 8$.

Comment: I posted a new answer using the quadratic field and $p$-adic number theory at the above URL.